# Can we have the posiblity to further filter remotely work by e.g. time zone

Tags: feature-request, jobs

i.e. I am only intererested in jobs where there there are at least some overlap of working hours for majority of other people working at same project

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail of what you want to be implemented?

Comment: like set filtering for telecommuting only to show jobs where normal working hours is my normal work hours (e.g. day time for where I live)

Comment: So there is some overlap in online hours. I.e. I would prefer to telecommute within Europe alternatively work with a US team that work early hours